# R - need to add a flag where code identifies a missing value in a column

Tags: r

Not sure if the title is clear but I'm looking to add a column that identifies groups where a name value in the Name column may be missing within that group.  Sample data...

```
 Group ID  Ind ID  Name
 100       1       Andy
 100       1       Mike
 100       2       Mike
 200       1       Mike
 200       2       Mike
 300       1       Andy
 300       1       Mike
 400       1       Mike    
 400       2       Mike    
 400       3       Mike    
 400       4       Mike
```

I want to add a fourth column that will have a flag whether "Andy" was not in the group at all.  So...

```
 Group ID  Ind ID  Name  Andy?
 100       1       Andy    Y
 100       1       Mike    Y
 100       2       Mike    Y
 200       1       Mike    N
 200       2       Mike    N
 300       1       Andy    Y
 300       2       Mike    Y
 400       1       Mike    N
 400       2       Mike    N
 400       3       Mike    N
 400       4       Mike    N
```

My initial thought was to partition the data and then loop to find if there are any mentions of the name I want to flag for in the Name column.

I used split() for the partition - after 5 minutes, it was still going. I do have a 600,000+ rows with probably 500,000 as unique group IDs.

Any advice on how to handle?

Comment: For grouping on that many groups, you'll want to look at the **data.table** package, or possibly **dplyr**. Probably the former will be faster for huge numbers of small groups like that.

Comment: I am actually using dplyr at the moment for aggregating the data / summing up values.  I'm not sure how to incorporate this though using dplyr

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter data:

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
##   text=
##  "Group_ID  Ind_ID  Name  Andy?
##  100       1       Andy    Y
##  100       1       Mike    Y
##  100       2       Mike    Y
##  200       1       Mike    N
##  200       2       Mike    N
##  300       1       Andy    Y
##  300       2       Mike    Y
##  400       1       Mike    N
##  400       2       Mike    N
##  400       3       Mike    N
##  400       4       Mike    N")
```

I tried to do this with `ave()` from base R, but it makes assumptions about the type of the return value that are problematic ... this might be faster anyway.

```
library("dplyr")
dat %>% group_by(Group_ID) %>%
    mutate(`Andy?` = "Andy" %in% Name)

## Source: local data frame [11 x 5]
## Groups: Group_ID
## 
##    Group_ID Ind_ID Name Andy. Andy?
## 1       100      1 Andy     Y  TRUE
## 2       100      1 Mike     Y  TRUE
## ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use data table and `any()`, using `GroupID` as the grouping variable.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, "Andy?" := any(Name == "Andy"), by = GroupID]
```

which gives

```
 #     GroupID IndID Name Andy?
 #  1:     100     1 Andy  TRUE
 #  2:     100     1 Mike  TRUE
 #  3:     100     2 Mike  TRUE
 #  4:     200     1 Mike FALSE
 #  5:     200     2 Mike FALSE
 #  6:     300     1 Andy  TRUE
 #  7:     300     1 Mike  TRUE
 #  8:     400     1 Mike FALSE
 #  9:     400     2 Mike FALSE
 # 10:     400     3 Mike FALSE
 # 11:     400     4 Mike FALSE
```

Or, for `Y` and `N` in the `Andy?` column, you can use

```
setDT(df)[, "Andy?" := ifelse(any(Name == "Andy"), "Y", "N"), by = GroupID]
```

A base R way is to use `ave()`  Although this doesn't really seem too desirable given how simple and efficient it is with `data.table` and `dplyr`.

```
df[["Andy?"]] <- with(df, {
    ave(as.character(Name), GroupID, FUN = function(x) {
        ifelse(any(x == "Andy"), "Y", "N")
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi Richard.  Did you mean to paste that text?

Comment: Thanks for revising!   having a look now

Comment: The `ave` solution is not horrible, but it is clunky in this particular instance.

Comment: @Richard Scriven - you used dplyr before and removed it.  Any reason why you thought it wasn't worth sharing?  More curious since I am using dplyr already

Comment: @AndyD I removed it because Ben Bolker posted basically the same thing.

Comment: @RichardScriven - this worked for me as well.  Thanks Richard!  I did set the entry from Ben as the answer since I'm using that but this is just as fast and I'll want to understand how both work.